# Define two radio button in MFC with same click action method

Tags: mfc

I trying to define two radio button in MFC ( VS 2010 ) that the action click of both of them will be same - that mean that in click action of each of them ... the method that will be called will be same method.

But the VS don't give me this option .. i getting message the method with the same name already exists.

How can i do it?

And how can i make those two radio button to be in same group ( that only one of them will be checked and the other will be unchecked ) ?

And how to set default checked on one of the radio buttons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the two method in the wizard, then manually remove one and point to the one you save in the message map.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Property Panel, and Set the "Group" attribute of the first Radio button. This will bind the two buttons in one group, and buttons within one group work mutual exclusively.